# Save photo to iPhone Photo album from dowloaded NSData object

Tags: iphone

I download the data from a URL of video in NSData form. Now how can I store it to iphone Photoalbum? Is there any way to convert NSData to video back or we can directly save it to photo album?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can play the movie in a MPMoviePlayerController object then it should return true when checked by UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum().

If so, then you can save it to the Photo Library using this function:

```
void UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (
   NSString  *videoPath,
   id        completionTarget,
   SEL       completionSelector,
   void      *contextInfo
);
```

Alternatively, you can create and ALAssetsLibrary object and save it using using the this method:

```
- (void)writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSURL *)videoPathURL completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```